# Inverse function for flipud

Tags: image, matlab, encryption

If I use `flipud()` function during encryption, I need to certainly use the function that performs the opposite of it during decryption.

Is there any function or piece of code that performs the inverse operation of `flipud()` function in MATLAB?

Comment: Is the inverse not just...flipping it again?

Comment: Yes,but should be done in the reverse order I think. Like, flipud will flip up to down, now in decryption I need to flip down to up.

Comment: Calling `flipud` twice does that.  Verify with `A = rand(100,100);`  `B = all(all(A == flipud(flipud(A))));`

Comment: Flipping down to up is still flipping up to down.

Comment: I am not sure I understand, `flipud` should certainly be a one to one mapping. This should be completely reversible by using the same method. This sounds much like the XY-problem. So I wonder, do you get any troubles in this stage? In that case I would assume the villain to be one of the previous steps.

Answer (score 5):

Just call `flipud` again.  `flipud` simply takes each column of your matrix and reverses the order so that the last row appears first.  To undo the reversal, if you perform `flipud` on the already reversed matrix.  The last row of the reversed matrix becomes the first row and so on, so you'll get the original order back.

Observe:

```
>> A = rand(100,100);
>> B = isequal(A, flipud(flipud(A)))

B =

     1
```

`A` is a random 100 x 100 matrix.  I used `isequal` to ensure that the original matrix is equal to the twice flipped matrix for every single element in this matrix.  However, if you don't want to get confused with the names.... if you really, really, really... I mean really.... want to have a function that "reverses" an already reversed matrix, you can call a function called `flipdu` that performs this flipping for you:

```
flipdu = @flipud;
```

Answer (score 5):

You can define a helper function, flip down-up, to accomplish what you need:

```
function [output] = flipdu(A)
%FLIPDU Flip array in down/up direction.
%   OUTPUT = FLIPDU(A) returns A with the order of elements flipped upside down
%   along the first dimension.  For example,
%   
%   A = 1 4      becomes  3 6
%       2 5               2 5
%       3 6               1 4
%
%   See also FLIPLR, ROT90, FLIP, FLIPUD.
output = flipud(A);  % Equivalent to flip(A, 1)
end
```